# Struggling to program a simple calculator

Tags: c, switch-statement, calculator, break

I am trying to program a simple calculator.
 Here is my code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) { 

char operator = 0;
float num1 = 0.0;
float num2 = 0.0;
float sol = 0.0;


while (operator != 'q') {

    printf("Operator: ");
    scanf("%c", &operator);
    printf("First Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Second Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    switch (operator)
    {
    case '+': sol = num1 + num2; break;
    case '-': sol = num1 - num2; break;
    case '*': sol = num1 * num2; break;
    case '/': sol = num1 / num2; break;
    case 'q': printf("Finished!"); exit(0);
    default: printf("Error!"); exit(0);
    }

    printf("The solution is: %.2f\n\n", sol); 
}

return 0;
}
```

So for me the code is fine. As you can see I did this with a while loop that lets you calculate until you type in 'q' as operator. The first run of the loop works fine but then it gets creepy (my console):

```
Operator: +
First Number: 5
Second Number: 4
The solution is: 9.00

Operator: First Number:
```

Why does the program not let me enter  an operator in the second loop run?

Comment: When you handle an error, don't just say "Error!".  You need to generate as much information as possible.
`printf ("Error!  Didn't expect operator %c (%d)\n", operator, operator);`

What's happening is you're capturing the newline at the end of the first line of input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most format specifiers with scanf will skip leading whitespace. `%c` does not.
`scanf("%f", &num2);` at the end of the first iteration leaves a newline in the input buffer.
`scanf("%c", &operator);` at the start of the second iteration, reads the newline and proceeds.
using a space before `%c` in `scanf(" %c", &operator);` will allow `%c` to skip the leading whitespace and capture the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `scanf` for errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char operator = 0;
    float num1 = 0.0;
    float num2 = 0.0;
    float sol = 0.0;

    while (operator != 'q') {

        printf("Operator: ");
        if((scanf(" %c", &operator)) != 1){
            printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("First Number: ");
        if((scanf("%f", &num1)) != 1){
            printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Second Number: ");
        if((scanf("%f", &num2)) != 1){
            printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (operator){
            case '+': sol = num1 + num2; break;
            case '-': sol = num1 - num2; break;
            case '*': sol = num1 * num2; break;
            case '/': sol = num1 / num2; break;
            case 'q': printf("Finished!"); exit(0);
            default: printf("Error!"); exit(0);
        }

        printf("The solution is: %.2f\n\n", sol);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and as you can see I changed `scanf("%c", &operator);` to this `scanf(" %c", &operator);` to make `scanf` to ignore (skip) `Whitespace`.